# QGIS legend horizontal not vertical

Tags: qgis, legend

Is there an easy way to have the legend linked to the size of the box it is drawn in.

So instead of running down the side of the page, it will be across the bottom in columns?

Does that make sense... I don't want it to run as a line across the bottom either but define my box with lets say 3 items in each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS 2+ legend items can be arranged in columns.

[image]

Comment: Doh...stuck in my way old me still using 1.8.  Only use 2 for some functions when 1.8 slips up.  WIll need to move to it full time now i thinks.